Recode a Variable if it Does Not Fall into a Set Python
I have a data set that looks like this. I would like to recode the values if they do not fall into a set.
If my set = (Apple, Orange) I would like all other values to be 'x'.
I have this column.
  a     
0 Apple
1 Apple
2 Pear
3 Banana
4 Apple
5 Orange 

I would like to make it look like this column:
  a
0 Apple
1 Apple
2 x
3 x
4 Apple
5 Orange


You will get better answers it you post some code or what you have tried already

Filtering dataframes is a common operation in pandas, this should be in most tutorials.

Use the isin() condition to filter the rows where the column is in your list. Then assign x to that column.
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Pear', 'Banana', 'Apple', 'Orange']})
fruit_set = {'Apple', 'Orange'}
df.loc[~df['a'].isin(fruit_set),'a'] = 'x'

